# Excel Formula - Comparing Range of Date

Tags: excel, vba

how to write EXCEL VBA to make my date from 04/JUNE > 04/JUNE 23:59. i cannot use the '= date + 5/6' as i have to run the VBA many times a day and it will add my dates to tomorrow/ the day after tomorrow. i just wanna make the date to end of date. please help.

The example will be like

CELL A1 : 12/June 
CELL B1 : 15/June
CELL C1 : 15/June 12:00 HRS
CELL D1 : =IF C1B2, “OUT OF RANGE”, “Okay !”)

in this case D1 will still display OUT OF RANGE.

I have loads of such to change so I was thinking of writing a VBA to automatically convert C1 from 15/JUNE -> 15/JUNE 23:59 , so that D1 will display Okay !

I tried Cdate(Range(“D1”)) + 5/6 in vba to make it 23:00 hrs and I run this macro a few times in a day and it will keep adding 23hrs to the date and made it change to another date.

Comment: Add the code you're using and doesn't work so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

About what you are talking?

About:
- *"Excel Formula"*  or
- *"EXCEL VBA"*
?

About:
- *"Comparing Range of Date"* or
- *"to make my date"*
?

Assume, that VBA is...

The `Date` type in VBA is `Double`, where:
- Integer part as quantity of days from... (look F1), and
- Fractional part of day.

So, your desired *"04/JUNE > 04/JUNE 23:59"* will:

```
? DateSerial(2018, 06, 4) + ((23& * 60& * 60&) + (59& * 60&)) / 86400&
18-06-04 23:59:00
```

Yeah, sure, you can use `TimeSerial`instead of above, but ... it didn't give you right understanding of VBA dates.
.

**----------**
**ADD:**

> Sorry but will this code only work for one cell because I have lots of
>   cells with dates and I need VBA to extract them out and convert to
>   23:59 for eg I run a for loop to change like 20 cells in a row with
>   multiple range. And I will run the macro a few times in a day will it
>   add 23hrs to that date every time and cause it to change dates ?

```
Public Sub sp_Test_Date()
Dim rSel As Range
Dim i&

Const H23M59 As Double = 1 - 60 / 86400

    Set rSel = Selection
    With rSel
        For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
            With .Cells(i)
                If IsDate(.Value) Then
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = CDate(Int(.Value) + H23M59)
                End If
            End With ' .Cells(i)
        Next
    End With ' rSel
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry but will this code only work for one cell because I have lots of cells with dates and I need VBA to extract them out and convert to 23:59 for eg I run a for loop to change like 20 cells in a row with multiple range. And I will run the macro a few times in a day will it add 23hrs to that date every time and cause it to change dates ?

Comment: i tried modifying it and it failed me. `    Dim x As Integer
    Dim test1 As Date
    Dim schdWS, compWS As Worksheet
    Const H23M59 As Double = 1 - 60 / 86400

    Set schdWS = Sheet1
    Set compWS = Sheet11
    lastrow = schdWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 20 To lastrow
        If IsDate(schdWS.Cells(x, 3).Value) Then
            Cells(x, 3).Value = CDate(Int(Cells(x, 3).Value + H23M59))
        End If
        
        
        
        'test1.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        'schdWS.Cells(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 = test1 & " 23:59"
    Next x
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

i tried modifying it to below and it failed me :(

```
 `
Dim x As Integer
Dim test1 As Date
Dim schdWS, compWS As Worksheet
Const H23M59 As Double = 1 - 60 / 86400

Set schdWS = Sheet1
Set compWS = Sheet11

lastrow = schdWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 20 To lastrow

    If IsDate(schdWS.Cells(x, 3).Value) Then
        Cells(x, 3).Value = CDate(Int(Cells(x, 3).Value + H23M59))
    End If



    'test1.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    'schdWS.Cells(x, 3).FormulaR1C1 = test1 & " 23:59"

Next x
```

End Sub

```
    `
```